# Moving average on list of (x,y) points in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy, moving-average

I have an array of points, [(x,y),...], collected from user mouse line drawing, I want to remove noise from it by using a moving average method.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: What do you define as 'noise'?

Comment: user hand vibration : extra points a  little far from main path

Comment: You could maybe apply, or adapt `potrace` to do it for you... http://potrace.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @AVEbrahimi it would be helpful if you gave us sample data to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using a **convolution** of size `s`:

```py
v = np.array([(0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (-1, 9), (3, 7), (4, 8), (5, 9)])
s = 2

kernel = np.ones(s)
x = np.convolve(v[:,0], kernel, 'valid') / s
y = np.convolve(v[:,1], kernel, 'valid') / s
res = np.hstack((x[:, None], y[:, None]))

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[0.5 4.5]
 [1.5 5.5]
 [0.5 7.5]
 [1.  8. ]
 [3.5 7.5]
 [4.5 8.5]]
```

The bigger `s`, the *smoother* the path. However, the bigger `s`, the *shorter* the path.

Answer (score 1):

See
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#filtering

or just use [convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html) and correct borders if it's necessary

If you can use opencv in your project, then see
https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html
and use

```
a = np.array(list_of_points, 'f') # should be floating
kernel_size = 3 # for example
filtered = cv2.blur(a, (1, kernel_size), borderType=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
```